# A fact about algebraic systems and axiom of choice

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, axiom-of-choice, universal-algebra, algebraic-logic

> Algebraic system $\mathfrak A$ contains a proper subsystem $\mathfrak B$ isomorphic to $\mathfrak A$. Prove that $\mathfrak A$ is contained in a proper supersystem $\mathfrak C$ isomorphic to $\mathfrak A$.

I know how to prove this using Tarski's theorem about choice (and, hence, axiom of choice).

The question is: Could this theorem be proved independently of axiom of choice? And, if so, how?

Comment: I actually don't see how choice is relevant here - the only proof I can think of *doesn't* use choice. What proof do you have in mind?

Comment: @Noah Schweber, let be $A$ and $B$ be the domains of $\mathfrak A$ and  $\mathfrak B$. Since $A$ is infinite, $|A|=|A^2|$. Let $C=A^2$ be a domain of $\mathfrak C$. Then we can define operations and relations on $\mathfrak C$ as images of operations and relations on $\mathfrak A$. Let $i:\mathfrak B\rightarrow \mathfrak A$ be the inclusion and $f:\mathfrak B\rightarrow \mathfrak A$, $g:\mathfrak A\rightarrow \mathfrak C$ the isomorphisms. Then $g\circ i\circ f^{-1}$ is the desired inclusion $\mathfrak A\subset\mathfrak C$.

Comment: @Noah Schweber, oh, I see we can use any $C$ such that $|C|=|A|$... :)

Comment: @MaximNikitin ...Such as $A$ itself!

Comment: (Composing the isomorphism $A\to B$ with the inclusion $B\to A$ gives a non-surjective embedding $i\colon A\to A$. Now if you want $A$ to literally be a substructure of a larger $C$, replace the elements of the image of $i$ by their preimages in $A$ and replace the elements not in the image of $i$ by some arbitrary set disjoint from $A$.)